# Subclass attributes are not populating in the superclass's database table as columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I have two boolean values in the subclass of a hibernate annotated superclass along with other few attributes:

```
private Boolean currentLoan;
private Boolean unpaidFine;

@Column(name="current_loan")
@NotNull
public Boolean hasCurrentLoan() {
    return currentLoan;
}

public void setCurrentLoans(boolean currentLoan) {
    this.currentLoan = currentLoan;
}

@Column(name="unpaid_fine")
@NotNull
public Boolean hasUnpaidFine() {
    return unpaidFine;
}

public void setUnpaidFine(boolean unpaidFine) {
    this.unpaidFine = unpaidFine;
}
```

When the hibernate creates the tables, the other attributes of subclass appear as columns in the table of the superclass except these two. I have noticed the other attributes are not of type *Boolean*. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "has" methods to "is" methods.  Also how are the other columns being declared that are working.  ex. `public boolean isUnpaidLoans()`